HTTP GET for All Push Locations not working
I am creating a script to get the list of all locations but the Get function is not retrieving anything. Here's my script:
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

var authEndpoint = 'https://domain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com';
var payload = {
    client_id: "client_id",
    client_secret: "client_secret",
    grant_type: "client_credentials"
};
var authurl = authEndpoint + '/v2/token';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var tokenResponse;

try {
    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(authurl, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
    } else {
        Write("Error obtaining access token. Status code: " + accessTokenRequest.StatusCode + ", Response: " + accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
    }
} catch (error) {
    Write("Error obtaining access token: " + Stringify(error));
}

if (tokenResponse) {
    Write(Stringify(tokenResponse));
}
  
// Base URL for Marketing Cloud Push API
var baseUrl = 'https://domain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com';

//Get All Locations
var url = baseUrl + '/push/v1/location';
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + tokenResponse.access_token];

var response = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);
  
var responseAllLocation= Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Response[0])
var listLocations = responseAllLocation.items
  
Write("<br>"+ Stringify(listLocations))
  

</script>

When I try to debug, I receive this error: ""Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame."
Why is it not working?

HTTP.GET returns the response object with attributes are Status and Content
Therefore you should parse the response like this:
......

var responseAllLocation= Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content);
var listLocations = responseAllLocation.items;
  
Write("<br>"+ Stringify(listLocations));
</script>

